# How to set up Redux Devtools in VScode ? (Using a Company Extension that blocks browser extensions.)

Tags: redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

Using a Company Laptop I tried installing redux devtools browser extension but access is disabled.

I have installed the Redux Devtools vscode extension and i want to set it up to run in localhost:

[image: VSCode Extension settings]

[image: Localhost with port]
[image: Not able to connect redux]

I have tried putting in "hostname:localhost" and "port:3000" and connecting but it doesn't work.